# Would someone write a regular expression for me in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

I recently asked for help with a regular expression; I now know I did not ask for enough!

Can somebody please compose for me a regular expression that will extract all numbers from a string. There could be a single instance of a number, there could be multiple instances of numbers, there will be other text in the string and each of the numbers may or may not contain decimal points. Where decimal points are present, there is no fixed precision. Numbers may also contain thousand seperators (normally a comma).

Examples:

- "(123 items with 234 sub items)" - results: "123", "234"
- "123 @ 234.56%" - results: "123", "234.56"
- "(123 @ 234.56%)" - result: "123", "234.56"
- "@ 123.45 %" - result: "123.45"
- "123 @ 4.56 p" - results: "123", "4.56"
- "12,345.67 and 2345.67" - results: - "12,345.67", "2345.67"

I will be using the .NET regular expression engine.

Comment: You need to also post what you have tried. Otherwise you're not asking for help, you're just asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: And what is exactly the question? Where is the problem? This question looks like the you have a homework and you ask us to do them instead of you.

Comment: jlafay: I have tried various attempts: "\w-?\d*(\.\d+)?\w" (sometimes works, often results in matches to empty spaces), "\d+" (gets whole numbers), ^-?\d*(\.\d+)? (again, sometimes works). All to no avail - RegEx is definitely my achiles heel!

Comment: TcKs: No, this is not homework, I just cannot get my head around regular expressions!

Comment: you need to provide your code examples (such as regex patterns) in your posts so we can see what isn't working. It's ok if you can't wrap your head around it, the syntax is tough. Just saying you need to provide an example of what you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"[0-9][0-9,.]*"`

Comment: This certainly works against all of the examples I have so far. And it is very simple too. Thanks.

Comment: I am going with this as my accepted answer as it matches all of my criteria and is so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most efficient but this matches all of the cases you specified:

```
[0-9]([0-9]|[,]|)*([\.][0-9]+|)
```

- [0-9] Ensures a single number is matched
- ([0-9]|[,]|)* Ensures that if there are any more numbers/commas after the first number, they are matched
- ([.][0-9]+|) Ensures that if a decimal point exists, its is matched (will not match if no numbers are specified after the decimal)

Comment: This would match "0,,,99,8000."

Comment: Your example will match "1,2,3,4" too

Comment: This certainly works against all of the examples I have so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `[-+]?\b\d+(?:,\d{3})*\.?\d*\b`

Comment: I tried this on http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and it failed to pull the value from "   @    9.100 %". Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's strange. I checked both my changed and unchanged versions and they matched.

Comment: I just tried it again and still got no results. Are you using any non-default options?

Comment: Following up on Brendans comment below, I just tried this in the project instead of the test web site and it worked correctly. Apologies for doubting you.

Answer (score 1):

This thing should ensure that you only get a comma every three numbers.

```
\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?
```

Comment: I tried this on http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and it failed to pull the value from " @ 9.100 %". Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Maybe you should try it in your .NET project; different engines can give different results.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Within the project, it matches everything correctly. Sorry for the original doubt.

Answer (score 1):

```
(0?|[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?((,[0-9][0-9][0-9])*|[0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Matches:

```
0.1234
1,234,567.23
1234567
234.0
.23
```

Will not match:

```
0.234,342
1234,2345
1,234,5678
123.
01234
```

Comment: (using .NET engine) this failed to extract the two numbers from "Sep  ( 6686  items less 420  charges)". Thanks though.